# Adding noUnusedLocals to tsconfig.json report false positive on all my tests(mocha)

Tags: typescript, mocha.js

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "typeRoots": [
        "./node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "moduleResolution": "node", 
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true
},
"exclude": [
    "./lib/**/*",
    "./node_modules/**/*"
],
"include": [
    "./src/**/*",
    "./test/**/*"
]
```

}

**Command**
tsc -w -p tsconfig.json --noEmit

When I run this I get all kind of "is declared but never used." but only on my mocha tests.

My normal code in src works fine and if I don't use a certain import or variable it complains as it should.

thanks

Comment: Can you add a minimal test case? What var is declare and never used?

Comment: k. I found the problem. What was happening is that there was some unused import but my editor did not mark them. I fixed them and now it compiles.See sometimes you just need to step away from a problem